# Display the data in the append table row then Submit or Insert to Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Good Day!

I'm just thinking and researching how can I execute the given problem to me.
My program has a `ADD` button then it will pop-up the Modal Form that you will input data then when you insert it will display in the table. Every time you add and insert those data it will append the table row at the same time it will display the data. This adding will not save or insert in database. I just I want to add then reorder those table.
Simple as I will make a list of ordering. When I'm done there's a `SUBMIT` button that will insert now the table row in the database.
Can someone give me an idea how I can do this?Or a sample demo that related to this?

Comment: what have you tried? see this example? http://jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php

Comment: Your given example is good. Actually I have program similar that one, but I need a submit button so that all the list should be save in the database. Let's say the the example you sent is just displaying the data in the table, when I'm done adding, editing or deleting all the list should be insert in the database.

Comment: you have to create some custome code for database with this...

Comment: What do you mean custom code?

Comment: use ajax with the addition function in js to store in database.

Comment: Oh ajax? I'm not familiar with that. In this case, for the table, I will get the data per row? Oh I'm sorry its hard to picture out so that I'm asking you this.

Comment: Is it also possible to for each() per row then using ajax pass the text per row to insert in the database?